# Using environmental variable in rabbitmq.conf file

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ in windows environment. I am using RabbitMQ with ssl configuration.
My requirement is to use environment variable in the rabbitmq.conf file to read SSL certificates. I have used it as below,

**{cacertfile, "${MY_HOME}/config/SSLCertificates/testca/cacert.pem"**

The above usage of environmental variable doesnt work. Can any one of you please help me in correct usage of environmental variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your variables to file `rabbitmq-env.bat` from the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-file) that's the location in windows:

> If rabbitmq-env.conf doesn't exist, it can be created manually in the location, specified by the RABBITMQ_CONF_ENV_FILE variable. On Windows systems, it is named rabbitmq-env.bat.

Also, you may need to use `%%` instead of `${}` since you are in windows.

[From the windows section](https://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.rabbitmq.2.4/configure.html)

> If you need to customise names, ports, locations, it is easiest to configure environment variables in the Windows dialogue: Start > Settings > Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables.

So after defining your environments, try this:

```
...
{cacertfile, "%YOURVAR%\path\to\cacert.pem"}
...

Windows: %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ
```

Comment: How would I access, for example, the value of **JAVA_HOME** variable?

Comment: This does not work for me, neither with `%%` nor with `${}`

Anybody has a working solution?

Comment: No, RabbitMQ do not allow to use env variables in configuration.